# Taylor series expansion, $f(x)=\frac{1}{4-x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

Find taylor series expansion of the following function:
$f(x)=\frac{1}{4-x^2}$
In the neighbourhood of the point $x_0=1$ determine the radius of convergence of this series. I do not understand the method i should apply here. How to deal with those type of questions?

Comment: It may be best to begin by finding the partial fraction decomposition of $f(x)$.

Comment: Since the closest zero of $4-x^2$ is $2$ you can immediately answer the question with the radius of convergence. It is $|x_0-2|=1$.

Comment: Have you seen how to expand something like $1/(x-2)$ around, say $x_0=-1$, so using powers of $x+1$? Surely your teacher didn't leave you hanging without giving any examples-

Comment: i do not think i saw something like that.

Comment: What did you see then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Here is a start $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{4 - x^2} &= \frac{1}{4(x+2)} - \frac{1}{4(x-2)}\\&= \frac{1}{4(x-1 + 3)} - \frac{1}{4(x-1 - 1)} \\&= \frac{1}{4(x-1) + 12} - \frac{1}{4(x-1) - 4}\\&= \frac{1}{12}\left(\frac{1}{1 +  \frac{(x-1)}{3}}\right) + \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{ 1- (x-1)}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: thus the Taylor expansion will be: $\frac{1}{3} (x-1) \frac{2x}{(x^2-4)^2}$?

Comment: No. The last equation gives you after a few modifications some very well known series expansion.

Comment: I think i do not understand....

Comment: One more step then.

Comment: Will it be $1/3+1/9(x-1)+7/81(x-1)^2 \ldots$

Comment: Almost that, you just need to work a bit more on those coefficients. But I believe you got the idea.

Comment: but first and the second coefficients are ok? because derivative of my function at $ x=1$ is equal to $\frac{2}{9}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27596/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-mkropkowski).

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor expansion around a point $x_0$ is the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^n/n!$. So the exercise is really to find all the derivatives of $f(x)$ at the point $x_0=1$.

Comment: Really? I think that in this case it is much easier to find the Taylor series expansion first, and the derivatives afterwards, if needed :-)

Comment: yes, you are right.